# How to ask the reason of sudden unfriendliness of neighbours?

Tags: rudeness, approach, neighbors

I recently moved to a new neighborhood where the houses are all pretty close. The neighbors were all pretty friendly at first, even helping with yard work, but suddenly became very standoffish. They are friends with the previous owners, who still hang out with them.

There are five families who are acting weird. They won’t even say hi to my kids, even if we have children around the same age.

My biggest concern is that my kids who are 1 and 4 will grow up feeling like outsiders. It really bugs me and makes me want to move, which isn’t really an option.

How to ask them about the possible reason for such a sudden behaviour change?

Comment: Hi Cakepan. What is your main goal, and what would you like to achieve?

Comment: Can you give us a rough timeline of when this started happening? What do you mean by "standoffish" and "weird", exactly - like your kids wave and say hi and they avert their eyes, or? Also, could you add a general location/culture tag?

Comment: I'm confused what's wrong with just asking them "What's the reason for such a sudden behavior change?" As written this looks more like a phrasing request than a question about navigating an interpersonal situation.